# Where to download lint-checks-27.0.0.jar for Android studio 4.0?

Tags: android

**When building the release APK, it always fails with the following error:**

```
Could not find lint-checks-27.0.0.jar (com.android.tools.lint:lint-checks:27.0.0).
```

**I'm in offline environment and use local repository in the build.gradle, and I want to download the lint-checks-27.0.0.jar by manually.**

```
repositories {
    maven { url '/path/to/repository' }
}
```

**I have checked the following maven central repository, but only found the 25.3.0 as shown below.**

```
https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/android/tools/lint/lint-checks/

...
25.1.0/                                           2016-04-26 22:20         -      
25.1.2/                                           2016-06-06 16:43         -      
25.1.3/                                           2016-08-24 04:20         -      
25.2.0/                                           2016-09-26 16:42         -      
25.3.0/                                           2017-03-06 17:42         -      
maven-metadata.xml                                2017-03-06 17:43      2383      
maven-metadata.xml.md5                            2017-03-06 17:43        32      
maven-metadata.xml.sha1                           2017-03-06 17:43        40
```

**I have also tried the following google and jcenter repositories, but can't find any artifect inside by using Firefox browser.**

```
https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/
https://jcenter.bintray.com/
```

**I have also tried the following URL but Firefox browser responses with 404 Not Found:**

```
https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/lint/lint-checks/lint-checks-27.0.0.jar
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `google()` repository should have it:

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.android.tools.lint/lint-checks/27.0.0

And I think your repository URL is wrong ...for comparision:

https://maven.google.com/com/android/tools/lint/lint-checks/27.0.0/lint-checks-27.0.0.jar

I don't understand why you haven't added the actual repository configuration, but it should be:

```
repositories {
    // maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
    google()
}
```